# x86 instruction encoding how to choose opcode

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86-64, disassembly

When encode instruction`cmpw %ax -5` for x86-64, from Intel-instruction-set-reference-manual, I have two opcodes to choose:

```
3D iw CMP AX, imm16 I Valid Valid Compare imm16 with AX.
83 /7 ib CMP r/m16, imm8 MI Valid Valid Compare imm8 with r/m16.
```

So there will be two encoding results:

```
66 3d fb ff ; this for opcode 3d
66 83 f8 fb ; this for opcode 83
```

Then which one is better?

I tried some online-disassembler below

- https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2
  https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/

Both can disassemble to origin instruction. But why `6683fb00` also works and `663dfb` doesn't.

Comment: There can be no "better" unless you say what's important to you. I can think of three dimensions: code size, execution speed, and compatibility/portability. Size seems to be the same, so it's not better there. There's probably more. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Without looking into this too far, one instruction seems to compare AX (a 16-bit register) with a 16-bit value, whereas the other compares a different (16-bit) register with an 8-bit value.

Comment: In the second variant, the prefix isn't length-changing.

Comment: @unwind maybe execution speed is more important for me since I am working on generate object file in a compiler directly.

Comment: @IraBaxter From the perspective of assembler, which should choose?

Comment: @harold so the second is better? I think gas and llvm will choose the second one.

Comment: In this case don't use a 16-bit immediate value if you don't have to. There is quite a penalty for the Length Changing prefix in 64-bit code. The [Intel optimization manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) has a rule to avoid an LCP stall like this: _Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 21. (MH impact, MH generality) Favor generating code using imm8 or imm32 values instead of imm16 values._

Comment: @Neil that doesn't matter if he's using -5 as the operand though

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks. I will refer to the manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both encodings are the same length, so that doesn't help us decide.

However, as @Michael Petch commented, the `imm16` encoding will cause an LCP stall in the decoders on Intel CPUs.  (Because without the `66` operand-size prefix, it would be `3D imm32`, so the operand-size prefix changes the length of the *rest* of the instruction.  This is why it's called a [Length-Changing-Prefix stall](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-performance-bottleneck-analyzer/topic/328256).  AFAIK, you'd get the same stall in 16bit code for using a 32bit immediate.)

**The `imm8` encoding doesn't cause a problem on any microarchitecture I know of, so favour it.**  See [Agner Fog's microarch.pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/), and other links from the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

It can be worth using a longer instruction to avoid an LCP stall.  (e.g. if you know the upper 16 bits of the register are zero or sign-extended, using 32bit operand size can avoid the LCP stall.)

Intel SnB-family CPUs have a uop cache, so instructions don't always have to be re-decoded before executing.  Still, the uop cache is small, so it's worth it.

Of course, if you're tuning for AMD, then this isn't a factor.  I forget if Atom and Silvermont decoders also have LCP stalls.

---

#### Re: part2:

`663d` is prefix+opcode for `cmp ax, imm16`.  `663dfb` doesn't "work" because it consumes the first byte of the following instruction.  When the decoder see `66 3D`, it grabs the next 2 bytes from the instruction stream as the immediate.

Comment: Awesome answer for the extra reference!