# add 1 byte immediate value to a 2 bytes memory location

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The `add` instruction documentation from [this page](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_5.html) says the following:

[image]

Notice the two instructions that I highlighted.

I tried the following code in NASM (which conforms with the first highlighted instruction):

```
add WORD [myvar], BYTE 0xA5
```

But I got the following error:

> warning: signed byte value exceeds bounds

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you try -91 instead of 0xA5?

Comment: or are you trying to add +165?

Comment: @old_timer `add WORD [myvar], BYTE -91` works, but `add WORD [myvar], BYTE 165 doesn't work`.

Comment: which are you trying to do -91 or +165?  If it is +165 then fuz answered your question and already said that byte 165 isnt going to work.  But if you were no trying +165 but instead -91 then use -91 instead of 0xA5 and fuz only partially answered your question.

Answer (score 8):

The 8-bit immediate operand (denoted here by `imm8`) is sign-extended into 16 (or 32) bits to match the size of the other operand (`r/m16` or `r/m32`, respectively).

Thus, only values between -128 and 127 can be represented, which is why you receive this warning from the assembler.

For the value 0xA5, you need to use a `WORD` immediate (`imm16`):

```
add WORD [myvar], WORD 0xA5
```

(although the `WORD` is optional on the source operand, since it is implied by the constant's size).

Comment: Almost always better to let the assembler choose the width of the immediate for you, and put the operand-size specifier on the memory operand when there's ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

I won't repeat @fuz's answer, but I want to add:

**If you had just let the assembler do its job by writing `add word [myvar], 0xA5`, it would have picked the smallest encoding that worked**.  If your immediate had fit in a sign-extended imm8, it would have used the `add r/m16, imm8` encoding.  There is usually no need to use size-overrides on non-memory operands.  All the major x86 assemblers optimize the size of immediate operands.  Some (e.g. NASM) will even optimize `mov rax, 1` into the equivalent but shorter `mov eax, 1`, and stuff like that, but others (YASM) won't.

You can force the assembler to use wider immediates than necessary for padding/alignment, though.  e.g. `add word [myvar], strict word 1`.  would use the `imm16` version.  (Without `strict`, it doesn't stop the assembler from optimizing it to a smaller encoding.)  You can also `add word [rcx + strict dword 0], strict word 1` to force a `[base + disp32]` encoding for the addressing mode.

---

When possible, **avoid 16-bit immediate operands to instructions other than `mov`**.  On many Intel CPUs, that instruction will be slow to decode, because of [an LCP stall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611247/x86-instruction-encoding-how-to-choose-opcode).  This might not be a problem on newer CPUs that have a decoded-uop cache.  But on older Intel CPUs, this will probably run faster, at the cost of a scratch register:

```
movzx  eax, word [myvar]
add    eax, 0xA5          # add ax, 0xa5 is 1B smaller, but has the same LCP stall.
mov    [myvar], ax
```

`add`/`sub` carry left-to-right, so the low part of a wider add is always the same as what you'd get from a narrow `add`.  Avoiding LCP stalls for register operands is usually cheap (just an extra 1B for the `add eax,imm32`, since it doesn't need an operand-size prefix), but the load and store are extra.

This is a lot more code-size, so it's probably slower on CPUs that don't have LCP stalls.  It's only 1 more uop for the front-end on Intel Sandybridge-family (which can micro-fuse the load+add in the one-instruction version), and the same number of uops for the execution units / scheduler.  (memory-destination instructions decode to load, ALU, and store uops.)

Comment: (Another option would be `mov eax, 0xa5` / `add [myvar], ax`, but that's more uops for the back-end and same total for the front-end on modern Intel: (1 + 2 = 3). The memory-dst add's load+add micro-fuses, and the store-address+store-data uops micro-fuse, so `add [mem],reg` is 2 front-end uops total, 4 back-end uops.  (Same total back-end uops as the movzx load; add reg,imm; mov-store; and that doesn't include a mov-immediate.)