# x86 assembly 16 bit vs 8 bit immediate operand encoding

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, opcode, instruction-encoding

I'm writing my own assembler and trying to encode the ADC instruction, I have a question about immediate values, especially when adding 8-bit value into the AX register.

When adding 16-bit value: `adc ax, 0xff33` gets encoded as `15 33 ff` which is correct.
But would it matter if `adc ax, 0x33` gets encoded as `15 33 00`?

Nasm encodes this into `83 d0 33` which is obviously correct, but is my approach correct as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's common for x86 to have more than 1 valid way of encoding an instruction.  e.g. most `op  reg, reg` instructions have a choice of encoding via the `op  r/m, reg` or the `op  reg, r/m` opcode.

And yes, normally you want an assembler to always pick the shortest encoding for an instruction.  NASM even optimizes `mov rax, 1` (7 bytes for `mov r64, sign_extended_imm32`) into `mov eax, 1` (5 bytes) for x86-64, changing the operand-size to use the zero-extension from writing a 32-bit register instead of explicit sign-extension of a 32-bit immediate.

#### Using the sign-extended-imm8 encoding when available is always good

It's equal length for 16-bit, but shorter for 32-bit operand-size, so it simplifies your code to always choose `imm8`.

With operand-size of 32-bit, `op  eax, imm32` is 5 bytes, vs. `op  r/m32, imm8` still being 3 bytes.  (Not counting any prefixes needed to set operand-size or other things; those will be the same for both.)

#### Performance advantages of the imm8 encoding

If an operand-size prefix is requires (e.g. in 32-bit mode for `adc ax, 0x33`), using the `adc ax/eax/rax, imm16/32/32` encoding with an operand-size prefix will create an **LCP stall on Intel CPUs** (Length-Changing Prefix means the prefix changes the length of the *rest* of the instruction.  This doesn't happen for the imm8 encoding because it's still (prefix) + opcode + modrm + imm8 regardless of the operand-size.

See  [Agner Fog's microarch.pdf](https://agner.org/optimize/) and other performance links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).   See also [x86 instruction encoding how to choose opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611247/x86-instruction-encoding-how-to-choose-opcode) which is a duplicate of this, except for the fact that `adc` is a special case.

---

In the specific case of `adc`/`sbb`, there is another advantage to avoiding the `ax, imm16` encoding:  See [Which Intel microarchitecture introduced the ADC reg,0 single-uop special case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664369/which-intel-microarchitecture-introduced-the-adc-reg-0-single-uop-special-case)  On Sandybridge through Haswell, `adc ax, 0` is special-cased as a single-uop instruction, instead of the normal 2 for a 3-input uop (ax, flags, immediate).

**But this special casing doesn't work for the no-ModRM short form encodings, so the 3-byte `adc ax, imm16` still decodes to 2 uops**.  Only the decoder for the `imm8` form checks if the immediate is zero before decoding to a single uop.  (And it still doesn't work for `adc al, imm8`.)

**So always choosing the sign-extended-imm8 whenever possible is optimal for this, too,** even in 16-bit mode where no operand-size prefix would be required for `adc ax,0` and thus the LCP-stall issue wouldn't happen.

---

Most assemblers don't provide an override to avoid the no-ModRM short form.  When they were designed, there wasn't a performance use-case other than intentionally lengthening instructions to get alignment without adding NOPs before the top of a loop or other branch target: [What methods can be used to efficiently extend instruction length on modern x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046814/what-methods-can-be-used-to-efficiently-extend-instruction-length-on-modern-x86)

If you're designing a new flavour of asm syntax you might consider allowing more control of the encoding with override keywords.  For existing designs, check out NASM's `strict` and `nosplit` keywords, and GAS's `{vex2}`, `{vex3}`, `{disp32}` and so on "prefixes"

- [How to force NASM to encode [1 + rax*2] as disp32 + index*2 instead of disp8 + base + index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848230/how-to-force-nasm-to-encode-1-rax2-as-disp32-index2-instead-of-disp8-b) for `nosplit` to force a longer more efficient encoding for LEA.
- [How do GNU assembler x86 instruction suffixes like ".s" in "mov.s" work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673177/how-do-gnu-assembler-x86-instruction-suffixes-like-s-in-mov-s-work) (GAS `{disp32}` and so on, and `{load}` or `{store}` to choose which of the `op r/m, r` vs. `op r, r/m` encoding you prefer.)
- [Sign or Zero Extension of address in 64bit mode for MOV moffs32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665819/sign-or-zero-extension-of-address-in-64bit-mode-for-mov-moffs32) In 64-bit mode, `a32 mov eax, [0x123456]` with the no-modrm `moffs` encoding causes an LCP stall on Intel CPUs.  It's shorter than modrm+SIB+disp32 for absolute addressing, but potentially slower.
- [Why NASM on Linux changes registers in x86_64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596247/why-nasm-on-linux-changes-registers-in-x86-64-assembly) NASM `mov rax,1` (5 bytes) vs. `mov rax, strict dword 1` (7 bytes) vs. `mov rax, strict qword 1` (10 byte `imm64` encoding)

Comment: Instead of  `strict` and `nosplit` I designed keywords `CODE=` ,`IMM=`, `DISP=` in my assembler, which I believe are more intuitive and elegant, as they allow to select opcode, immediate operand and ModR/M displacement encoding independently, see for instance https://euroassembler.eu/eatests/t3043.htm