# Which is the "right" way to encode "add ax, 0x22"?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, machine-code, opcode

It seems that this 8086 instruction:

```
add ax, 0x22
```

Can be encoded in two different ways: `83 C0 22` and `05 22 00`.

Microsoft Macro Assembler compiles it into `05 22 00`, whereas the Keystone Assembler compiles it into `83 C0 22` (https://alexaltea.github.io/keystone.js/).

Is one of the two options considered "wrong"?

If not, then does either option have any advantage over the other?

Comment: Both are correct and the same length, equivalent for all practical purposes. If you had `add eax, 0x22` that would be different because the `05` opcode would take 4 bytes of immediate while the `83` could do with a 1 byte sign-extended. Conversely, `add al, 0x22` would be 2 bytes with the `05` opcode but 3 with the `80`.

Comment: Semi-related: [x86 instruction encoding how to choose opcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37611247) in 32-bit mode, the `op ax, imm16` form has an LCP stall with the `66` prefix necessary to encode it, but the `op  r/m16, imm8` doesn't.  But in 16-bit mode there are no disadvantages to either encoding for this instruction.  `adc ax, 0x22` would be different; again the imm16 would be worse because for some reason [Which Intel microarchitecture introduced the ADC reg,0 single-uop special case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664369) doesn't apply.