# Is "strb w0, [x2, w3, uxtw]" the same as "strb w0, [x2, w3, uxtw #0]"?

Tags: assembly, arm64, instructions, addressing-mode, instruction-encoding

I'm totally puzzled.

I thought that the following instructions are totally the same:

```
strb    w0,[x2,w3,uxtw 0] 
strb    w0,[x2,w3,uxtw]
```

but when I assemble them, I get different encoding:

```
40 48 23 38     strb w0, [x2, w3, uxtw]
40 58 23 38     strb w0, [x2, w3, uxtw #0]
```

Any ideas why that's happening?

Comment: Perhaps related: [What do the \`uxtx\` and \`sxtx\` extensions mean for 32-bit AArch64 \`adds\` instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72041372) mentions a different redundancy in addressing-mode encoding, between `ldr x0, [x1, x2, sxtx]` and `ldr x0, [x1, x2]` (implicitly `uxtw`, but both are "extending" from 64-bit to 64-bit.)  I'd assume your case is another case of redundant ways to encode the same thing when the shift count is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are syntactically different, but semantically equivalent.

Long story short: it's the shift bit.
The two instructions you show differ in bit 12 (dubbed `S` in the manual), which determines whether the index register is to be shifted or not. This works the same for all `strb`, `strh` and `str` instructions. The index is always shifted to match the size of the stored operand, so in the case of `str xN` it's 3, in `str wN` it's 2, in `strh` it's 1, and in `strb`, well, it ends up being 0.

Thus you get this line in the manual, on `strb`:

```
<amount>    Is the index shift amount, it must be #0, encoded in "S"
            as 0 if omitted, or as 1 if present.
```

So one of your instructions doesn't shift the index, the other one shifts it by zero. Great success.